# muting start-up sound on Lion

Tags: macos

How can I permanently mute the start-up sound on Lion?

[StartupSound.prefPane](http://www5e.biglobe.ne.jp/~arcana/index.en.html) isn't compatible with Lion. I found [Psst](http://www.satsumac.com/Psst.php), and I guess it's the best option, but it still looks like a hack. Any better ideas?

Comment: Would a shutdown item that mutes the volume be acceptable?

Comment: @bmike that doesn't sound like too bad an option. Do you know how to do that? If so, can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Before I start up my MacBook in the library, I plug in a headset or earbuds (from my phone or iPod).  Hardware mute.  Works with either OS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but:

I keep the volume of my MacBook to zero (so no sound on startup) since I do not want sound without earphones or my stereo connected anyway - Mac OS saves different volume settings for “something plugged in” and “nothing plugged in”.

At least, works for me.